# PHP retweet syntax for twitter REST api v1.1 won't retweet from statuses/mentions_timeline array

Tags: php, twitter

I'm in the process of setting up a test bot for retweeting tweets from my user statuses/mentions_timeline.
I really need some help with grabbing the status ID from the array of mentions the script creates, so that I can use the statuses/retweet/:id resource to then retweet mentions

Here's the code, I won't include the Auth Tokens but they are there and I have no problems posting status updates.

```html
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
$tweets = $twitter->get('statuses/mentions_timeline', ['count' => 200]);
$tweets1 = $twitter->get('users/show', ['count' => 170]);
$totalTweets[] = $tweets;
$page = 0;

$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
for($count = 20; $count < 21; $count += 20) {
 $max = count($totalTweets[$page]) - 1;
 $tweets = $twitter->get('statuses/mentions_timeline', ['count' => 20, 'max_id' => $totalTweets[$page][$max]->id_str, 'screen_name' => 'UnkindRTs', 'include_rts' => false]);
 $totalTweets[] = $tweets;
 $page += 1;
  
}
$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
$start = 1;
foreach($totalTweets as $page) {
 foreach($page as $key){
  echo $start . ':' . $key->text . '<br>';
  $postconn = $twitter->post('statuses/retweet/'.$key->text.id_str);
  $start++;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out thx for all the help though! XD

changed 
$postconn to

```php
$postconn = $twitter->post('statuses/retweet/'.$key->id_str);
```

only had a small error xD